# Getting 502 error on long query only over https

Tags: graphql, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, apollo-server

I have a rather long query on my gql server, the resolver calls a grpc method. when I run this locally it works, but when I make the query on our development deployment(https) the request comes back with

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

There are other grpc calls that work, over https as well. So I don't think it is any issue there..

In the gcp logs I can actually see the result from the resolver logged. although in the browser it comes as a 502 error.

my resolver

```
train: async (parent, args) => {
      const { projectId, yml } = args
      let result = await nluTrain(projectId, yml);
      return { done:result }
    }
```

my server

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req, connection}) => {
    if(req){
      return {
        req,
      };
    }
  },
});


server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);
httpServer.listen({ port: 8001 }, () => {
  console.log('Apollo Server on http://localhost:8001/graphql');
});
```

Comment: How long is the request running for?  It's really likely the connection is being closed early, which should normally be a 504, but this could be due to how the connection is terminated.

Comment: @HMilbradt pretty reliably, exactly 30 seconds.

Comment: Based on the question tags, this seems to be running on GKE. Furthermore, 502 codes are usually associated to resources relaying requests and network issues. It might be important to include the Kubernetes object definitions involved to determine if the error is coming from a misconfiguration there.

Comment: Seems to be an Apollo Server issue, 502 is returned from Apollo Server once large queries (lots of fields to return) are made (probably only with considerable loads, which i tested), and these are only occurring to GraphQL services on my cluster (also GKE), not a single non-GraphQL service experience the same issue, not even with high large bodied high loads.